# Problem exporting from mongo and then importing to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-query

Question: how do I export from mongo such that I can import into SQL Server if I use $unwind?

I need to use $unwind which means I can't use mongoexport.exe. Mongo.exe gives different output for json as shown below. Output I can't load into SQL Server. I would export as csv output, but my data includes commas. I would use $out to first copy my data to a new collection & then use mongoexport, but I'm querying a production server in the cloud where I only have read access.

To illustrate my problem, I created a collection with one record that has a date field "edited_on". You can see here that mongoexport output starts with ["_id:{$oid....  while mongo output starts with {"_id : ObjectID(….

*** MONGOEXPORT

> The command:
>
> > mongoexport --quiet --host localhost:27017 --db "zzz" -c
> >     "Test_Structures" --fields edited_on --type json --jsonArray --out
> >     C:\export_test.json
>
> The output:
>
> > [{"_id":{"$oid":"5aaa1d85b8078250f1000c0e"},"edited_on":{"$date":"2018-03-15T07:15:17.583Z"}}]

I can import this data into SQL with OPENROWSET along with OPENJSON.
Described here:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5295/different-ways-to-import-json-files-into-sql-server/

*** MONGO

> The command:
>
> > mongo localhost/UW --quiet -eval "db.Test_Structures.aggregate( {
> >     $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1} } )" > C:\aggregate_test.json
>
> The output:
>
> > { "_id" : ObjectId("5aaa1d85b8078250f1000c0e"), "edited_on" :
> >     ISODate("2018-03-15T07:15:17.583Z") }

Answer (score 0):

Declare @JSON varchar(max)

My coworker answered my question. Use replace() to remove the text in the json file that are causing problems as follows.

> SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
>           FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\aggregate_test.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
>           SET @JSON = replace(replace(replace(@JSON,'objectid(',''),'isodate(',''),'")','"')
>
> SELECT *  FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)  With (...)